# Java Compilation error on Mac

Tags: java

I have been coding with Eclipse and testing the code using Terminal on OS X 10.7.4. When I ran the code with Eclipse, it worked. However, running with terminal gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: PacketPrinter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I checked my java and javac version. They are both 1.7. I have been googling but could not find anything.

Comment: Check which JRE eclipse is using, my bet is that it's not the same as the default JRE in your $PATH

Comment: Eclipse is using JRE 1.7. In my $PATH, I did not see anything about Java though

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using the same runtime on the command line as when you launch the program from within Eclipse.

Try executing

```
java -version
```

from the command line to see which version of java you're using on the terminal.

(You can also run `which java` to see exactly which file is being executed.)

Comment: Like I said above, the version of java running on terminal is 1.7

Comment: I executed 
which java
and it showed that /Library/Java/Home/bin/java is being run. I saw that I had only Java 1.7 in my machine by the way

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a different version of java running in eclipse and in your terminal.

Do the following:

In the terminal type: java -version
In eclipse goto the preferences and look in Java/Installed JREs

Compare the versions.

Point you $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables to the same JRE you use in Eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse, I found only 1.7 in Java/Installed JREs, which is strange since it should have 1.6 as preinstalled.

Also, how can point $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables to the JRE? Could you please explain a bit more clearly? Thank you

Comment: For testing you can just type PATH=$PATH:<Path to jdk/bin> and JAVA_HOME=<Path to jdk>

If you want to add the settings permanently, open ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.profile, check which one is already there) and make your changes there...

Answer (score 0):

As aioobe said check you java version using following command

```
java -version
```

Copy the contents of the PATH settings to a notepad and check if you have any other java version path present in it and if it is before that of the 7. If so, remove that path in the PATH setting and save it.

I would suggest you to re logging after doing it.

AFAIK this error comes when you have older version java path present in path.

Comment: This is what I got when I did the command
echo $PATH

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin